# Get only new members in a multi-select field on change?

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-designer

I have a people picker field that allows multiple selections. When this item changes, I would like to email new users that they have been added to the list. What I need to avoid is spamming the existing users every time someone is added to the list. Is this possible within SharePoint Designer / OOTB functionality?

I have identified a suboptimal solution which involves creating a separate "Add User" workflow. However, this complicates the design for my users and I would like to let them stay within the standard list item editor if at all possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using code you can create an ItemUpdated EventReceiver, in that you'll be able to compare BeforeProperties and AfterProperties which has the old and new values of each modified field.

But if you're limited to SharePoint Designer, then I think the only solution is an extra field which contains users to which we've already sent out mails and some very complex logic (most likely involving a helper list) to send out mails based on differences.

I definitely think the EventReceiver is the easiest.